# Vert.x 2 -> Vert.x 3 communication over EventBus

Tags: vert.x

I have quick question - did anyone tried to run both - Vert.x 2 and Vert.x 3 applications in a cluster, communicating over EventBus?

Theoretically it should be possible but has anyone done it?;)

Cheers,
Michał

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm much appreciate the question since I personaly got the same thought when I decided to upgrade my *2.x* application to the latest release version of *Vert.x*, i.e. the *3.x*.

I guess you are exposing such a problematic because the inter-node / inter-module communication protocols should be at least compatible to some extend, and the `EventBus` is already the inter module communication channel in a typical *Vert.x* application and is expected to abstract away message transfers even between different modules versions.

Meanwhile I don't know any open source product which provides API compatibility between major versions as a major version generally denotes **"APIs will change"**. *Vert.x* should be with no exception, and it comes with no surprise that communication can fail between verticles / modules developed in different versions, thus such an approach should be avoided even don't deserve tests.

Comment: Yeah... I know, but I had to try ;)

Comment: I managed to run them both in one cluster (after doing some very nasty hacks and having both vert.x 2 and 3 on classpath) but I didn't manage to make any calls between these two instances.

I ended up with wire-level errors:
SEVERE: Unhandled exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid wire protocol version 11 should be <= 1
 at MessageImpl.readFromWire(MessageImpl.java:178)
SEVERE: Unhandled exception
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index: 7, length: 1393229824 (expected: range(0, 83))
 at AbstractByteBuf.checkIndex(AbstractByteBuf.java:1134)

Answer (score 3):

For the 3.3 release Vert.x is adding a new module to the 2.x series. This new component is `mod-eventbus3-bridge-client`.

The idea is that you can deploy this module along your existing 2.x application and it will bridge between the eventbus 2.x and eventbus 3.x.

You can see the code at: https://github.com/vert-x/mod-eventbus3-bridge-client/tree/initial-work

So in Vert.x3 you would need to do:

```
public class Example {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    TcpEventBusBridge bridge = TcpEventBusBridge.create(
        vertx,
        new BridgeOptions()
            .addInboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions())
            .addOutboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions()));

    bridge.listen(7000, res -> {
      // example: vertx3 send a message to vertx2
      vertx.eventBus().send("send3", new JsonObject().put("msg", "hello send"));
    });
  }
}
```

And on Vert.x2 you would do the reverse:

```
public class Example extends Verticle {

  @Override
  public void start() {
    final EventBus3 eb = new EventBus3(vertx, getContainer().config(), new Handler<Void>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(Void done) {
        // case #1 vertx3 send a message to vertx2
        eb.registerHandler("send3", new Handler<BridgeMessage>() {
          @Override
          public void handle(BridgeMessage msg) {
            System.out.println(msg.body());
          }
        });
      }
    });

    eb.exceptionHandler(new Handler<Throwable>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried both Vert.x2 and Vert.x3 EventBus in cluster. But not at the same time. 
Vert.x2 required jdk 1.7 and Vert.x3 required jdk 1.8 or higher. I tried to run Vert.x2 in jdk 1.8 but that wasn't succeed.

thus, I think running both Vert.x2 and Vert.x3 applications in a cluster not possible.

Comment: I managed to run them both on JAVA 8 so this is not a problem. I described the problem in response to tmarwen comment.